# Objective-C: Where is the pointer that corresponds to an instance variable of an object stored

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, memory-management

Suppose I have the following class definition

```
@interface ClassX: NSObject
@property NSArray *arr;
@end
```

Suppose I have the following lines in a method

```
-(void)someMethod
{
  ClassX *obj = [ClassX new];
  obj.arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2], [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], nil]; //Edit to avoid getting derailed by differences due to @ notation
}
```

What is in the stack, what is in the heap?

Stack:

obj in the stack.  Value of this variable is the address of the place in the heap where obj resides.

Heap:

Object of type ClassX

What about the NSArray and the NSNUmbers within the NSArray?  Are they also divided as above?  I.e The pointer to the NSArray is in the stack and the NSArray object is in the heap?  If yes, what is contained in the heap memory that contains the "obj" object?

The figures I have seen are that this block of memory in the Heap contains a `isa` pointer and then instance variables.  The `isa` pointer point to the location of the `Class structure`.  I.e this piece of memory contains another isa pointer followed by `Method structs`. Each struct has a `selector` and a `pointer` to where the corresponding implementation starts.

This seems to suggest that the area variable within the object is in the heap.  I.e the pointer to the NSArray object is in the heap.

**EDIT**
Based on answers below, is this a correct view of what is there in heap and stack?

The stack will contain 4 pointers, One to obj, one to NSArray, two to NSNumber objects.

The heap memory that starts at the address pointed to by `obj` has
1. the `isapointer` pointing ClassX class structure
2. Followed by memory to store NSArray object.

This NSArray object memory has
1. isapointer pointing to NSArray class structure
2. followed by memory to store 2 NSNumber objects.

The NSNUmber object memory contain 
1. A isapointer pointing to NSNumber class structure
2. Followed by memory to store 2 ints

Comment: You have a constant array with constant contents, so the array and numbers will be in the data segment of your app. `obj.arr` will contain a reference to the static array in this data section. `obj` will be in the heap.

Comment: @Paulw11 That's what happens with regular arrays, but it is not what happens to @-initialized arrays and @ constants.

Comment: @Paulw11, what do you mean by data segment?  Is this on the heap or on the stack?  What if I the array is a NSMUtableArray instead of NSArray?   My main question is what is in the stack and what is the content of the memory in the heap.  I have put my understanding based on current answers under `Edit` in the question above.  Can you take a look?

Comment: The [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) is neither heap nor stack; it's a region of memory whose (initial) values are copied directly from your program's binary.

Comment: Note that objective-c objects can never be on the stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `NSArray` and `NSNumber` objects are heap-allocated, not stack-allocated.

They do not look like heap objects because the compiler hides it from you using the relatively new syntax `@[]`.

When you write

```
@[@1, @2]
```

The compiler translates it to

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: {[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2]} count: 2]
```

The end result is as follows: the stack has a pointer to an object of type `ClassX`. The memory pointed to by this pointer starts with an isapointer, followed by a pointer to another location in the heap that has `NSArrray` object in it. In turn, this part of heap memory has another isapointer followed by a pointer to a block of memory representing the inner array of `NSArray`, containing two pointers to `NSNumber` objects. Each of the `NSNumber` objects has an isapointer followed by data which represents the number.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight I was not concerned about the @ notation.  I have edited my question above to remove this.  My main question is what is in the stack and what is the content of the memory in the heap.  I have put my understanding based on current answers under `Edit` in the question above.  Can you take a look?

Comment: @SmartHome no, it's incorrect to say that the stack has four pointers; it has only one. The other three are embedded within other objects, all in the heap. These pointers may have been placed on the stack during construction, but once the calls are over, they are inside heap objects.

Comment: Thanks.  So, it looks like stack has pointer to an object of type Class X.  The memory pointed to by this pointer, will start with a isapointer.  It will then have a pointer to another location in the heap that has the NSArrray object.  In turn this part of heap memory will have another isapointer followed by two pointers to NSNUmber objects and so on. Is that correct?  if yes, can you please make it the answer , so I can accept it?

Comment: @SmartHome Yes, the description from your comment is correct.